# not able to get the bounding box of an element in blockly only in latest Firefox

Tags: position, bounding-box, blockly

There seems to be a bug in the latest version of Firefox when trying to retrieve the absolute position of a field within Blockly.
I am building a custom field that works a somewhat like the text input field. I need to get the absolute position of the field in the window, which I can get by calling

element.getAbsoluteXY_()

this is working fine on Safari, chrome and even IE, and the older versions of Firefox. But it seems broken (unless I made a non trivial mistake) in the latest Firefox.

Context : I am superimposing a text editor on a field, which works well and gives the impression that a block contains an editor.

Did someone step into this problem (bug ?)

Damir

Comment: Exactly what versions of Firefox are you comparing? what OS are you running on?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.
I'm running OSX 10.13.2 (High Sierra) and Firefox 59.0b9 (dev. edition). The same behaviour happens on v58.0.1. 
In the mean time, I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour with a simpler example.